# Get a column values based on anther column using python

Tags: python, pandas

How to get a column values when dates are between some dates like 2015-01-01 and 2015-03-01 or create a new DataFrame of all columns for  dates between  2015-01-01 and 2015-03-01

This is my current code:

```
 from datetime import date
 from nsepy import get_history
 sbin = get_history(symbol='SBIN',
                       start=date(2015,1,1),
                       end=date(2015,1,10))
```

This is the input data:

```
Symbol Series  Prev Close    Open    High     Low   Last   Close  \
Date
2015-01-01   SBIN     EQ      311.85  312.45  315.00  310.70  314.0  314.00
2015-01-02   SBIN     EQ      314.00  314.35  318.30  314.35  315.6  315.25
2015-01-05   SBIN     EQ      315.25  316.25  316.80  312.10  312.8  312.75
2015-01-06   SBIN     EQ      312.75  310.00  311.10  298.70  299.9  299.90
2015-01-07   SBIN     EQ      299.90  300.00  302.55  295.15  301.4  300.15
```

I have a DataFarme that has data for many years and i quite often need to plot small samples of it (different samples based on the dates) and i would need a function to split my dataFrame based on some dates. for instance, a new dataFrame with the same columns but for these dates only 2015-01-01 -2015-03-01

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You posted a bit of code and data, but what exactly is your problem here?!

Comment: @GhostCat unfortunately the answers below haven't helped me and i updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparisons for dates just like for anything else

```
# This will be true for every row that is true for both of these comparisons
idx = (sbin.index >= date(2015,1,1)) * (sbin.index <= date(2015,3,1))

sbin.iloc[idx].loc[:, ('Open', 'Close')]
new_sbin = sbin.iloc[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question entirely but here's how I interpreted it:

Scenario 1: you just want to grab the **rows** of your dataframe whose date column lie between a certain range. You can do this using pandas df.loc like this...

```
#Create a dataframe similar to yours
d = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime.date(2015,01,01), datetime.date(2015,01,02), datetime.date(2015,01,05), datetime.date(2015,01,06), datetime.date(2015, 01, 07)], 'open': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

new_df = d.loc[(d['date'] >= datetime.date(2015,01,01)) & (d['date'] < datetime.date(2015,01,05))]
```

This returns the rows whose dates lie between 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-05 (not including 05).

Scenario 2: You want to get a specific column's values based on your above date condition. You can do this like this...

```
another_df = d.loc[(d['date'] >= datetime.date(2015,01,01)) & (d['date'] < datetime.date(2015,01,05)), 'open']
```

We simply specify the column name which we want to grab info from based on the date condition, in this case the 'open' column.